# Send custom email by using cron job magento2

Tags: magento-2.1, module, cron, send-mail, abandoned-cart

I want to send an Email through a cron job for every 24hrs once.In that email need to mention all the abandoned cart details.
I am new to Cron jobs so can you please explain it. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

create new module **`Vendor_Module`**

create a new file **`crontab.xml`** at this location:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/

and insert below code

[image]

create new file **`Customemail.php`** at the location:

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Cron/

and code as below

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Cron;

class Customemail
{

    public function execute()
    {

        //send custom mail

    }
}
```

try this solution

Comment: Thank You Mohit .Not i got an idea about cron.

Comment: Can you provide the execution code ? I need that.